# using auto variables for global scope

Tags: c

```
auto int a=5;
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

I have read that the scope of automatic variables is within the specified block . In the above program, since the auto variable 'a' is declared outside main function, it should be assigned global scope and be accesible within the main . But, there seems to be an error .

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't think that's true. it'll just output 5 (or whatever) and then come out with the command line prompt immediately afterwards. If that starts with a carriage return, that'd be an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables at top-level cannot be `auto`. They should be either declared `static`, `extern` (definition elsewhere) or global (no keyword for that).

This won't compile.

```
$ echo "auto int c;" > test.c
$ gcc -Wall -c test.c
test.c:1:10: error: file-scope declaration of ‘a’ specifies ‘auto’
```

Comment: I have read that by default the variables are automatic variables in c. For this piece of code

 int a=5;
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{

    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;

}

Doesn't it mean variable a is an automatic variable? If yes, why does it work in this case?

Which languages support automatic variables under global declaration?

Comment: @VarunKumarChepuri: they're `auto` inside functions only.

Comment: What is the default variable outside functions?

Comment: @VarunKumarChepuri: global scope, i.e. external linkage (variables are visible in other modules of the program as well).

Answer (score 5):

In C, global scope `auto` variables are not allowed. Per definition they are function-local variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Auto** variables can be only accessed within the block/function they have been declared and not outside globally.

In C Programming by default, these variables are auto which is declared in the function.